# Passing scope variables between nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have some nested directives as follows:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <parent sku="12345">
          <child>
          </child>
       </parent>
    </div>
```

Both the parent and child directives have an isolated scope but I need to share the SKU attribute value between the parent and the child so that the child has access to this value. This value will always be hardcoded in the HTML.

Ideally, I would like each of the directives to have their own individual controller as well as a parent controller that sits over the top of both (MyCtrl) and I was intending on giving each directive their own isolated scope and then picking and choosing which scope values I want to share between them. The problem is I dont know how to do this.

Plunkr can be found here...

https://plnkr.co/edit/2M4OMNdXHlzq2MG9ugo0?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to have HTML structure like you posted? Then you will need to deal with transcusion and render child somewhere inside parent template.

Comment: I currently have the HTML like that and have separate template file for the child and parent directives

Comment: This doesn't answer my question regarding sharing the scope values though

Comment: It actually answers :). But I can repeat it: with this structure you need to manually transclude parent content, then you can control scope.

Comment: Can you give me an example please in my plunkr...would be appreciated

Comment: I like what Aleksey suggests, check it out. With transclusion it could look like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/KlE4Ssl33arojhjeZRI9?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `getSku` method to parent controller and then get this value in `link` function of child. Here's [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LQKymUg48pTk0XM1DYmf?p=preview).
If you're using angular 1.5.* can also checkout [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication) syntax. You'll be able to get similar results without `link` function.

Comment: I like this answer as it allows you to keep the scopes isolated and have more control over what is passed in. I think this is also what the angular documentation suggests having looked at it. Using the transclusion option seems a bit convoluted for the requirements

Comment: Could you give me an example of the same thing with the components syntax please Aleksey?

Comment: Sure, here's [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rb6fUb7xgsebR2r14MmG?p=preview) with the components

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. Perfect examples!

Comment: Expanding on this a bit...let's say in the parent controller you use a service to retrieve product data based on the sku used in the attribute. Is there any way we can use a callback that when this has finished the child directive retrieves this data

Comment: One of the options would be - expose method in parent `registerCallback` (like `getSku`), save the callback in array or something - and then invoke all the callbacks (passed from childs) when data availiable

Comment: I see. Because I am thinking something like getSku should really be something in the service shouldn't it? The actual http request to fetch the product data would be inside the service so on success I could set the sku in the service based on the response and return this variable so that the directives can access this globally?

Comment: Not necessary. You could return `promise` from service and then wire callback to this `promise` in controller

Comment: Hi Aleksey, do you have a quick demo for this?

Comment: something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/NHGGqVJEuncBNVMS2aLy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks again Aleksey...how would I pass multiple callbacks functions into this though?

Comment: you can register any number of callbacks (call `onGotIp` few times). or you can change `onGotIp` signature and get array of callbacks as input

Comment: I understand calling it multiple times but how would I pass multiple callbacks into the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115040/discussion-between-midda25-and-aleksey-l).